# Ajax call with jQuery in ASP.NET MVC does not pass parameters

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax, parameters

The Route is:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Ajax", // Route name
    "BizTalk/Services/{action}", // URL with parameters
    new
    { // Parameter defaults
     controller = "BizTalk"
    }
   );
```

My Controller is:

```
public JsonResult AjaxTest(string s, int i, bool b)
  {
   return Json("S: " + s + "," + "I: " + i + "," + "B: " + b);
  }
```

My jQuery Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#btn_test").click(function() {
    var s = "test";
    var i = 8;
    var b = true;
    $.ajax({
     type: "POST", cache: false,
     url: "/BizTalk/Services/AjaxTest",
     data: { i: i, s: s, b: b },
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     dataType: "json",
     success: function(msg) {
     }
    });
   });
  });
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This [post](http://web.archive.org/web/20111122170050/http://blogger.forgottenskies.com/?p=252) explains the problem and a possible solution (similar to how @Erv has explained).

If you remove `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"` from your call to `jQuery.ajax` the default content type (form-urlencoded) will be used and the json data you have specified as your data parameter (`data: { i: i, s: s, b: b }`) will be mapped correctly to your action parameters....so unless you really want to send json data just remove the contentType and you will be fine.....

Answer (score 2):

ASP.NET MVC does not automatically map incoming JSON data into action method parameters.

See the following article for a solution to add that capability:

http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/15/sending-json-to-an-asp-net-mvc-action-method-argument.aspx

Also, I think your jQuery call does not actually send JSON although that seems to be what you want it to do.  jQuery will not automatically convert the `data` object to JSON.  You need to convert it to JSON yourself with something like [json2.js](http://www.json.org/js.html)

Answer (score 1):

how did you get that "jquery ... does not pass parameters"? have you tried to sniff the request with firebug?

you're sending data in POST body but trying to access them in regular way (with using action arguments) like GET.
all POST data is in `Request.Form` or you have to handle it by binding to some custom `ViewModel`.

Answer (score 0):

Erm, might be wrong but you are passing in the jQuery i, s, b but in the action you have s, i,b .

The order must be correct for jQuery posts.

**EDIT**

Here is how I use jQuery posts;

jQuery

```
        $.post("/Articles/jQueryAddComment", { commentText: commentText, id: id, type: commentType }, function(returnedHTML) {
//Do something with the returned html.
        });
```

In my controller

```
        public ActionResult jQueryAddComment(string commentText, int id, string type)
        {
//do some stuff
                return PartialView("CommentList", fvm);
        }
```